# Using Redis to store user information

Tags: database, redis

I'm building a simple game type application where I have user authentication. I'm planning on using Redis for my database, and I was wondering what the best practice was to store users? What I understand is that I'll need a list or sorted set to store the users, and each user would be a hashmap. Is this the preferred method of storing users or is there a more optimal way?

Comment: Your should store the data in Redis based on how you're going to access it. A Hash per user usually makes sense. The Sorted Set may or may not fit here, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about it a sorted set is a little silly, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A hash per user works best in most cases. Redis [documentation](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) on data types mentions:

> Redis Hashes are maps between string fields and string values, so they are the perfect data type to represent objects (*e.g. A User with a number of fields like name, surname, age, and so forth*):

Comment: Could you help me, please?
I've role in user data, do you know how to save this data in  redis hash?
user: {"username": "Abc" "password:"123", roles: { "app": [1,2,3,4,5,6] } }

Answer (score 0):

Single hashmap per user is enough to store string/number/boolean type variables as string. If you want to store array per user, string/number/boolean array, you should also use a set  or list per user. If you want to store object array per ser, i think you should store each object as a hashmap and store keys of these hashmaps in a set or list for each user.